# Sending commands and strings to Terminal.app with Applescript

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I want to do something like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
  activate
  do script "ssh user@server.com"
  -- // write user's password
  -- // write some linux commands to remote server
end tell
```

For example to log in to the server, enter the password, and then login to mysql and select a DB.
I type that every day and it would be **really** helpful to bundle it into a script.

Also, is there a reference of what commands, properties, functions, etc. do applications (Terminal, Finder, etc) have available to use within Applescript? thanks!

**EDIT**: Let me clear this up:
I don't want to do several 'do script' as I tried and doesn't work.
I want to open a Terminal window, and then emulate a human typing in some characters and hitting enter. Could be passwords, could be commands, whatever, just sending chars to the Terminal which happens to be running ssh. I tried keystroke and doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

First connect to the server and wait for 6 seconds (you can change that) and then execute whatever you need on the remote server using the same tab

```
tell application "Terminal"
   set currentTab to do script ("ssh user@server;")
   delay 6
   do script ("do something remote") in currentTab
end tell
```

Comment: will these wait for completion? I mean when does ```do script``` return?

Answer (score 21):

As EvanK stated each do script line will open a new window however you can run
 two commands with the same do script by separating them with a semicolon. For example:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "date;time"
end tell
```

But the limit appears to be two commands.

However, you can append "in window 1" to the do script command (for every do script after the first one) to get the same effect and continue to run as many commands as you need to in the same window:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "date"
    do script "time" in window 1
    do script "who" in window 1
end tell
```

*Note that I just used the who, date, and time command as an example...replace
with whatever commands you need.*

Comment: “But the limit appears to be two commands.” Not at all. You can provide as many commands as the shell will accept, which is only limited by the total length of the line, not the number of commands.

Answer (score 19):

Here's another way, but with the advantage that it launches Terminal, brings it to the front, and creates only one window.

I like this when I want to be neatly presented with the results of my script.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set shell to do script "echo 1" in window 1
    do script "echo 2" in shell
    do script "echo 3" in shell
end tell
```

Comment: Very nice! It should be added, that if the commands itself contains the `"`-character, it must be escaped as `\"`

Answer (score 9):

How about this?  There's no need for key codes (at least in Lion, not sure about earlier), and a subroutine simplifies the main script.

The below script will ssh to localhost as user "me", enter password "myPassw0rd" after a 1 second delay, issue ls, delay 2 seconds, and then exit.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    my execCmd("ssh me@localhost", 1)
    my execCmd("myPassw0rd", 0)
    my execCmd("ls", 2)
    my execCmd("exit", 0)
end tell
on execCmd(cmd, pause)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Terminal"
            set frontmost to true
            keystroke cmd
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
    delay pause
end execCmd
```

Comment: How would I call my execCmd(passwd, 0) where passwd is a variable which has been set previously? set passwd to "myPassw0rd" ?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to "tell" Terminal to do anything. AppleScript can do shell scripts directly.

```
set theDir to "~/Desktop/"
do shell script "touch " & theDir &"SomeFile.txt"
```

or whatever ...

Comment: does this approach also run everything in only one window or would it open a new instance of Terminal for each "do command"?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't use expect:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set currentTab to do script ("expect -c 'spawn ssh user@IP; expect \"*?assword:*\"; send \"MySecretPass
\"; interact'")
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

The last example get errors under 10.6.8 (Build 10K549) caused by the keyword "pause".

Replacing it by the word "wait" makes it work:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    my execCmd("ssh me@localhost", 1)
    my execCmd("myPassw0rd", 0)
    my execCmd("ls", 2)
    my execCmd("exit", 0)
end tell

on execCmd(cmd, wait)
    tell application "System Events"
       tell application process "Terminal"
          set frontmost to true
          keystroke cmd
          keystroke return
       end tell
    end tell

    delay wait
end execCmd
```

Comment: adding delay 3 after the activate improved the running of the script in yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is specifically about how to get Applescript to do what
you want.  But, for the particular example described, you might want
to look into 'expect' as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Kinda related, you might want to look at Shuttle (http://fitztrev.github.io/shuttle/), it's a SSH shortcut menu for OSX.

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken, but I think Applescript Terminal integration is a one-shot deal...That is, each `do script` call is like opening a different terminal window, so I don't think you can interact with it at all.

You could copy over the SSH public keys to prevent the password prompt, then execute all the commands joined together (**warning: the following is totally untested**):

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "ssh jdoe@example.com '/home/jdoe/dosomestuff.sh && /home/jdoe/dosomemorestuff.sh'"
end tell
```

Alternatively, you could wrap the ssh and subsequent commands in a shell script using [Expect](http://expect.nist.gov/), and then call said shell script from your Applescript.

Comment: You can send a series of commands to one Terminal shell just by using multiple "do scripts".  Append "in window 0" and they use the frontmost window I believe.

Comment: No, it seems that do script actually tries to execute a script (as you would expect) which in some way is different than just sending the string to the terminal and hitting enter, because it didn't work as if I just entered the password.

Comment: what about `do shell script ssh user:password@server.com` to avoid the password prompt.

Comment: “…it seems that do script actually tries to execute a script (as you would expect) which in some way is different than just sending the string to the terminal and hitting enter…” No, it’s basically as if you had typed it…or more precisely, it’s as if you Pasted the text. You’re probably running into the issue that prompting for the password flushes input, so you need to wait for the prompt to appear before you send the password. But, as others have pointed out, don’t send your password, just arrange for automated authentication.

Answer (score 1):

set up passwordless ssh (`ssh-keygen`, then add the key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server).  Make an entry in `~/.ssh/config` (on your desktop), so that when you run ssh mysqlserver, it goes to user@hostname...   Or make a shell alias, like gotosql, that expands to `ssh user@host -t 'mysql_client ...'`  to start the mysql client interactively on the server.

Then you probably do need someone else's answer to script the process after that, since I don't know how to set startup commands for mysql.

At least that keeps your ssh password out of the script!

Comment: Ok thanks. But the password was just an example, the point here is that I want to send several strings to the terminal, no matter if they're passwords, mysql commands or whatever.

Comment: Yeah, I got that.  But we sysadmins _hate_ it when people put their passwords into plain text files all over the place.

Comment: :) Ok, thanks for the advice. But I'm the only user in my computer, and besides, the user and password I use to log to the ssh server is shared by a lot of employees all over the world so security doesn't look to be an issue for the company.

Comment: /facepalm.  It doesn't matter that you're the only user.  File permissions defend against other users on the same machine.  It's viruses and other attack vectors into your account that are the concern.  If pwning your machine gives direct access to the more-valuable server, that's a bad thing.

Comment: Do you even know about Mac OS and the subject here or just wanted to make a sysadmin rant? You didn't even try to answer the question. That's what this is about, making questions and answering them. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I got carried away with the sysadmin rant.  My answer started as a suggestion for an alternative way to do what you want with just ssh features, but then I realized you needed to do a bunch of interactive stuff on the remote side, so it didn't end up being as helpful as I hoped, and then I got the rant rolling.  I have used OS X, and I have scripted terminal sessions with mrxvt on Linux, but I haven't scripted OS X's terminal.  Sorry for being a jerk. :(

Answer (score 1):

Petruza,

Instead of using keystroke use key code.
The following example should work for you.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Terminal"
        set frontmost to true
        key code {2, 0, 17, 14}
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

The above example will send the characters {d  a  t  e}
to Terminal and then
 keystroke return will enter and run
the command. Use the above example
 with whatever key codes you need
and you'll be able to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"

    activate
    do shell script "sudo dscl localhost -create /Local/Default/Hosts/cc.josmoe.com IPAddress 127.0.0.1"
    do shell script "sudo dscl localhost -create /Local/Default/Hosts/cc.josmos2.com IPAddress 127.0.0.1"

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

As neat solution, try-

```
$ open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app  *.py
```

or

```
$ open -b com.apple.terminal *.py
```

For the shell launched, you can go to Preferences > Shell > set it to exit if no error.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I built this script. It is in Yosemite and it is bash script using AppleScript to choose a list of users for SSH servers. Basically you define an IP and then the user names.. when the application launches it asks who you want to login in as.. the SSH terminal is launched and logged in prompting a password...

```
(***
 * --- --- --- --- ---
 * JD Sports Fashion plc
 * Apple Script
 * Khaleel Mughal
 * --- --- --- --- ---
 * #SHELLSTAGINGSSHBASH
 * --- --- --- --- ---
***)

set stagingIP to "192.162.999.999"

set faciaName to (choose from list {"admin", "marketing", "photography_cdn"})

if faciaName is false then
    display dialog "No facia was selected." with icon stop buttons {"Exit"} default button {"Exit"}
else
    set faciaName to (item 1 of faciaName)

    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "ssh " & faciaName & "@" & stagingIP & ""
    end tell

end if
```

I highly recommend though; [Nathan Pickmans post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19965530/596952) about Shuttle (http://fitztrev.github.io/shuttle/).. a very smart and simple application.