# Automator action to connect to remote server and run svn update

Tags: svn, automator

I have a number of sites managed with Subversion and want to simplify the process of running an update on the remote server. i.e I want to have automator launch terminal, connect to a remote server with SSH and then run svn update in a specific folder...

Any ideas greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: That doesn't give me any control over when svn update runs though, I want it to be a manual process but I'm looking to reduce the key presses required to make it happen. :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realise "automator" was a thing.  I assumed you just meant "automatic"!

Comment: Is it windows-based (at your side) solution?

Comment: Sorry, yes lack on context. Automator is an OS X app which allows you to use a drag/drop interface to create automated processes which can run as workflows, service or applications (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all! I seems to have found a solution in the approach detailed here:

[Sending commands and strings to Terminal.app with Applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870270/sending-commands-and-strings-to-terminal-app-with-applescript)

:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use public key authentication with ssh and run based on a post-commit-hook which remotely runs an update on the particular server.