# Applescript to mount remote file system through sshfs with password authentification

Tags: macos, ssh, applescript, sshfs

I am using sshfs (with [OSXFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io/)) to mount a remote file system on a local directory. In the terminal it looks like

```
sshfs username@myremoteserver.com: /path/to/local/directory
```

Then it asks for my password and done.

**How can I include this in an applescript?**

I tried

```
do shell script "sshfs username@myremoteserver.com: /path/to/local/directory"
```

but it does not do anything, which I expect is because it is waiting for a password. I don't know how to prompt securely for a password, pass it to bash and run the ssh command. **Ideally I would like to do this without opening a terminal window.** Note that the password may change all the time so that I cannot use the Keychain Access.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28253149/2441318) is similar but only works for the superuser password.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use an SSH key for authentication, instead of a password?

Comment: @Kenster, I am not familiar with SSH keys, but I expect that I would need root permission on the remote server, which I have not. I have just been given a password, which changes often, so I can't use Keychain or similar.

Comment: @Kenster, actually, the problem is not root permission, but the administrators of the remote server do not allow SSH keys.